# Continuous Deployment using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: deployment, web-deployment-project, web-deployment

I have to deploy a website asap and then incrementally keep on adding some features, fixes. In Visual Studio 2008, I used to transfer/copy website where I could see in the dialog which file on my system is different from the server and deploy only that particular change.

But that dialog seems to have been taken down in Visual Studio 2010 and a one click publish has been put in place. How do I publish just the files I have added/modified. I am thinking of doing FTP client like FileZilla but keeping track of changes then becomes a headache.

What is the best way for site deployment in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326445/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-msbuild-scripts)

But if you fancy a quick & dirty solution (and since you haven't mentioned TFS or continuous integration, i assume you do), then write a robocopy script to only copy newer files.  But then again; [Using Robocopy to deploy sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694290/using-robocopy-to-deploy-sites/3740357#3740357)