# For asp.net boilerplate core version, robocopy required for publish

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

When doing a "dotnet publish" on windows for a freshly downloaded asp.net boilerplate template, everything works fine, and the resulting puplish folder can be used.

However when doing the same on linux, I get the following:

```
/bin/sh: 2: /tmp/tmpda90e7b4d99846c4936a6816fb7d9654.exec.cmd: robocopy: not found
```

Is there a specific way I am supposed to do a publish for asp.net boilerplate on linux?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694290/using-robocopy-to-deploy-sites

Comment: Robocopy is windows specific. The question is about creating a publishable folder for asp.net boilerplate on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AspNet Boilerplate merged solution has a **PrepublishScript** that executing a `Robocopy` step. Since Linux OS has no Robocopy command, you need to remove the below line in your **MyProject.Web.Host.csproj**

```
<Exec Command="robocopy $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\dist\ $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\ /S /E /MOVE" IgnoreExitCode="True" />
```

[Click here to go to the related source code line.](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template-docker/blob/9f415070eb13d47a958c550122416f329e51f0e1/src/AbpTemplate.Web.Host/AbpTemplate.Web.Host.csproj#L66)

And you need to make that step manually; copy the content of the `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\dist\` to `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\`

PS: **MSBuildProjectDirectory** is the property that will give you the full path to the project file which was invoked on the command line

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you.